# Can't show the user's detail data in html (but can show the array with print_r()) "codeigniter"

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to show the user detail modal when I click the detail button next to every that users name, but the problem is I can't display the "user_detail" data that I got from controller, it make me so confusing *because when I display from controller using **print_r()** it show perfectly the data array that I want*. Now I just want to display it as html like I display all user in the first place.

Here is my full code, I think we should just focus on the `get_detail()` method in the controller.

model/test_model.php:

```
function get_user()
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM tb_users ");
    $result = $query->result_array();   
    return $result;        
}

function get_detail($user_id)
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM tb_users where user_id = '".$user_id."'");
    $result = $query->result_array();   
    return $result;
}
```

Controller/Welcome.php:

```
public function index() 
{
    $data["datakcp"] = $this->test_model->get_user();
    $this->load->view('welcome_message',$data); // do this by loading a "view" that formats the data we gather here
}

public function get_user($user_id = null) 
{
        // get the user_id from the ajax request
        // this means if $user_id is set (not null) then make $user_id = $user_id. Otherwise, make $user_id = posted input
        $user_id = ($user_id) ? $retailer_id : $this->input->post('user_id');

        $datadetail= $this->test_model->get_detail($user_id);

       echo json_encode($datadetail);
}
```

Views/my_view.php:

```
<div class="container" style="width:700px;">  
    <h3 align="center"> </h3>  
    <br>  
    <div class="table-responsive">  
        <table class="table table-bordered">  
            <tr>  
                <th width="70%">Employee Name</th>  
                <th width="30%">View</th>  
            </tr>  
            <?php foreach($datakcp as $user){ ?>  
            <tr>  
                <td><?php echo $user["user_name"] ?></td>  
                <td><input type="button" name="detail" value="detail" id="<?php echo $user["user_id"] ?>" class="btn btn-info btn-xs view_dawta"></td>  
            </tr>  
            <?php } ?>  
         </table>  
     </div>  
 </div>  
 <div id="dataModal" class="modal fade">  
     <div class="modal-dialog">  
         <div class="modal-content">   
             <div class="modal-body" id="employee_detail"> 
             <table>
                 <thead>
                     <th>Username<th>
                     <th>Campaign</th>
                 </thead>
                 <tbody id="userDetail">
                 </tbody>
             </table>
         </div>   
     </div>  
 </div>
```

My jQuery ajax script:

```
 <script>  
      $(document).ready(function(){  
        $('.view_dawta').click(function(){  
            var user_id= $(this).attr("id");  
            $.ajax({  
                url:"index.php/Welcome/get_user",
                method:"post",

                data:{user_id:user_id},  
                success:function(data){  
               console.log(data)
                    $.each((JSON.parse(data)), function(key, value){
                        $('#userDetail').append(
                            '<tr>'+
                            '<td>'+value.user_name+'</td>'+
                            '<td>'+value.campaign_name+'</td>'+
                            '</tr>'
                            );
                            });
                    $('#dataModal').modal("show");
                }   
            });  
        });  
    });  
</script>
```

Comment: var_dump() your query result that you are getting from database

Comment: I just did, and it succesfuly show the array same as I using print_r() in my controller ,but still I want to show them in my view as html . like using foreach() to show all users in the first place

Comment: check here  echo json_encode($datwa); what is $datawa. you are assigning details to $datadetail["userdetail"] . after receiving data from ajax console.log(data); check whats the response from ajax. that help you to debug it more

Comment: my bad(updated it again),but still not affect anything ,but when i try console.log(data) .in show on debugger the json data that i need `[{"id":"2","user_id":"R22","user_name":"Ronaldo xx","campaign_name":"Never Top up","tag":"Never Top up","status":"4","created_time":"2018-03-28 14:27:34","phone_number":"0856464543",}]`

Comment: @VerdaniellTovarian with foreach loop is your problem solving?

Comment: when firsrt I show looping all user it's work,and I really want to display the detail user using foreach loop as well, can you please tell me how can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get_user` function is not returning anything. (Note: when you try your `print_r` or `var_dump` statement, the output of `print_r` or `var_dump` statement is returned, and otherwise nothing is being returned).

Put `echo json_encode($datadetail);` at the end in `get_user` function and receive `json` data in response. You will then have to use and format that `json` data in your `ajax` success function.

Alternatively, you can return formatted `html` from `get_user` function, in which case your `$('#employee_detail').html(data);` should work as it is.

**EDIT:**

1- Here is a basic `ajax` call you should use to receive `json` data:

```
$.ajax({  
    url:"index.php/Welcome/get_user",
    method:"post",
    contentType: "application/json;",
    dataType: "json",
    data:{user_id:user_id},  
    success:function(data){  
        $('#employee_detail').html(data);
        $('#dataModal').modal("show");
    }  
});
```

2- And in your `get_user` function, put `echo json_encode($datadetail);` at the end. At this point, you should be able to see `json` data in your modal.

3- In `get_user` function, replace `$datadetail["userdetail"]` with `$datadetail`. And at the end of the function, `echo json_encode($datadetail);`.

4- In `my_view.php`, construct a table inside `<div class="modal-body" id="employee_detail">` like below (this is just one way, you can decide a different approach if you wish):

```
<table>
   <thead>
       <th>Username</th>
       <th>Campaign</th>
       <!-- include more <th> tags for other user data -->
   </thead>
   <tbody id="userDetail">
   </tbody>
</table>
```

5- In `ajax` call, your `success` function can be:

```
success:function(data){  
    $.each(data, function(key, value){
        $('#userDetail').append(
             '<tr>'+
             '<td>'+value.user_name+'</td>'+
             '<td>'+value.campaign_name+'</td>'+
             /* include more <td> tags for other user data */
             '</tr>'
         );
    });
    $('#dataModal').modal("show");
}
```

6- This should be enough to give you a complete idea of how to receive and handle `json` data and also format it into html. This should be able to get you started. You can work on other formatting details etc. now.

On a related note, you have duplicate `user_id` in your returned data. Do check that.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I just put echo json_encode() , but the modal still didn't show anything, mayber you right it has something to do with the ajax(I'm still newbie with the ajax)can you please help me throught just edit my code above

Comment: `{"userdetail":[{"id":"2","user_id":"R22","user_name":"Ronaldo xx","campaign_name":"Never Top up","tag":"Never Top up","status":"4","created_time":"2018-03-28 14:27:34","phone_number":"0856464543","user_id":null,"feedback":"noAnswer"}]}`

Comment: that's one of the json data from one user's detail that i click and show on the modal .< I want to show every user_id,user_name,campaign_name,tag,phone_number, of the user

Comment: Check complete edit of my answer, it's updated now. This should be able to get you started and you can build further on this.

Comment: it showing the table ,but inside the <td> is "undefined " insted of displaying user_name and campaign_name?

Comment: did you replace `$datadetail["userdetail"]` with `$datadetail`? if not, then iterate over `data.userdetail` rather than `data` in `.each()`.

Comment: (1) In your `get_user` function, replace `$datadetail["userdetail"]` with `$datadetail`. (2) Replace `echo json_encode($datwa);` with `echo json_encode($datadetail);`. (3) In `.each` function, replace `data.kcpdetail` with `data`. (4) Please pay attention to the help. If you had carefully followed the edit to my answer, it was enough to get you started without errors.

Comment: my bad(updated it again),but still not affect anything and show nothing,but when i try console.log(data) after `success:function(data)`.in show on debugger the json data that i need `[{"id":"2","user_id":"R22","user_name":"Ronaldo xx","campaign_name":"Never Top up","tag":"Never Top up","status":"4","created_time":"2018-03-28 14:27:34","phone_number":"0856464543",}]`

Comment: Look at point (4) in edit of my answer and then look at your `my_view.php`. How can you access `#userDetail` when you haven't even defined it in html? Again, please take your time and pay attention to the help you get here. It's helping neither of us going over the same thing again and again.

Comment: Here's a [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/71701/) (with `.each()` function and without ajax) based on the edit to my answer and with the `json` data you provided. You can see that it's working. If you are getting `json` properly like you said, then it should also display just like in this example. If this doesn't help you, I'm sure someone else will be able to help you. Good luck.

Comment: it work man perfectly when I first click detail id , but unfortunately when I click antoher detail id or second click it show the old data in previous click ,do you why is that or how to prevend that happen? thank you so much xuhaib

Comment: I think you mean that old data from previous click is ALSO showing. Replace `append` with `html` in `success` function of `ajax`. As I said earlier, this should get you started and you can further build from this point as per your requirements. I believe your question has been adequately answered and you are able to display data now. So if all this help has been useful to you, then don't forget to vote the answer and accept it. That will be helpful for future users with similar issue.